# tagit : limiting tag creation to the given list by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tag-it

i am using a jquery ui plugin for tagging :

https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

im having a few issues :

1. when a user selects from the list, i want to save the id and the value for that tag.
2. only create tags from the list brought back by the AJAX call

   ```
   $(function() {
     $('#tags').tagit({tagSource:function( request, response ) {
   $.ajax({
   type:"GET",
   url: "http://some_link",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   data:{
       term:request.term,
       }, 
       success: function( data ) {
           response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
               return {
                   label: item.label,
                   value: item.value,
                   id:item.id
               };  
           }));
       }   
       });
   }
   , triggerKeys: ['enter', 'comma', 'tab']});
   });
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In answer to your second question Chris Leishman's fork of the Tag-It repository contains a new property `requireAutocomplete`  which allows only items in the autocomplete list to be used as tags.

You can find his pull request here: https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/pull/37

Download this version of the JS file from: https://github.com/chrisleishman/tag-it

and use it like an ordinary property:

```
$(selector).tagit({
        requireAutocomplete: true,
        tagSource: [...]
});
```

As for your first question, I'm working on this myself so I'll update my answer when I've found a solution.

I've made an amendment to my own local TagIt.js at line 271 changing:

```
var tag = that.createTag(ui.item.value);
```

to

```
var tag = that.createTag(ui.item.label);
```

which fixed the issue whereby the Id of the items shows instead of the label after choosing an option from the autocomplete list.

**Update**

Here's some information on how to save the ID's of each tag.

The first thing I did was override the `createTag` method to include a labelName parameter (you can modify the origional if you want, I just prefered to override it).

```
$.ui.tagit.prototype.createTag = function (labelName, value, additionalClass) {
 // The origional code from createTag here
}
```

Trim the labelName in the same way that the current value param is trimmed:

```
value = $.trim(value);
labelName = $.trim(labelName)
```

Change the label variable to use the new labelName:

```
    var label = $(this.options.onTagClicked ? 
      '<a class="tagit-label"></a>' :
      '<span class="tagit-label"></span>').text(labelName);
```

In the autocomplete section of the origional source I change the call to createTag to include the new label:

```
var tag = that.createTag(ui.item.label, ui.item.value);
```

Comment: regarding the first question, tagit saves the selected values in a hidden field, what i want is it to set 2 hidden fields.. i mean
we have 1. full name, short name and id..
when selected, i want to display the short name, but i want to save the full name and the id separately,

Comment: do you think its a good idea if i save them in a json format, inside the hidden field ?

Comment: I've actually found a way of saving the values correctly. I'll write up what I did and add it to my answer above.

Comment: See my update @NaumanBashir. As for saving the full name and ID, is there a good reason to save the full name along with the ID? You could customise tagit a bit further to put your full name into the hidden field it creates. Perhaps that's a bit overkill though if you've got the ID available?

Comment: hey jamie, i came up with a simple solution, kinda morphed your solution for handling multiple values...i will answere below

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19865908/2218697) is **another solution** , which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

this solution is for handling multiple values and the answer to the question :

when a user selects from the list, i want to save the id and the value for that tag.

Its inspired by the solution above (so you would need to read that :- ) ):

```
var tag = that.createTag(ui.item); // since ui.item will have everything, label, value, id and other things
```

then in the createTag function

```
var item = value;
value = item.value;
...
 var tag = $('<li></li>')
            .data('tag_item_data',item)// add this line
            .addClass('tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all')
            .addClass(additionalClass)
            .append(label);
```

now to retrieve the tags, just create a function

```
 assignedTagsData : function(){
         // Only to be used when singleField option is not seletced
        var tags = [];

         this.tagList.children('.tagit-choice').each(function() {
                tags.push($(this).data('tag_item_data') );
            });
         return tags;

    }
```

Comment: how did you handel Enter, because the autocomplete select is not fired when you hit eneter to selct the suggestion. i think it goes and calls _cleanedInput in tag it library