# jquery autocomplete select user and populate user id

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-autocomplete

I have a form where the user types a name and autocomplete populates the text input.
It works with the following code:

```
var names = [<?php 
    $tmp = Array();
    foreach($usernames as $row) 
    $tmp[] = '"'.$row->firstname.' '.$row->lastname.'"'; 
    echo join(',', $tmp);
?>];

$( "#employee" ).focus().autocomplete();
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="employee" id="employee" class="required"/>
```

I am now trying to take this further where the users id gets populated into a hidden field but i am struggling. The names array is fine but it no longer renders the autocomplete, so as you start typing nothing appears. (This is being used within modal).

Here is the code i am trying to use, does anybody have any ideas why i cant get this working?

```
<input type="text" name="employee" id="employee" class="required"/>
<input type="hidden" name="employee_id" id="employee_id" class="required"/>
```

**JS**

```
    $(function() {
    var names = [<?php 
    $tmp = Array();
    foreach($usernames as $row) $tmp[] = 
    '{
                value: "'.$row->firstname.' '.$row->lastname.'",
                label: "'.$row->firstname.' '.$row->lastname.'",
                desc: "'.$row->id.'",
    }'; 
    echo join(',', $tmp);
?>];
    });

$(document).ready(dialogForms);
function dialogForms() {    
 $('a.menubutton').click(function() {
    var a = $(this);
    $.get(a.attr('href'),function(resp){
      var dialog = $('<div>').attr('id','formDialog').html($(resp).find('form:first').parent('div').html());
      $('body').append(dialog);
      dialog.find(':submit').hide();
      dialog.dialog({
        title: a.attr('title') ? a.attr('title') : '',
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
          'Save': function() {
                submitFormWithAjax($(this).find('form'));
                $(this).dialog('close');
                },
          'Cancel': function() {$(this).dialog('close');}
        },
        close: function() {$(this).remove();},
        width: 600,
        height: 500,        
        show: "fade",
        hide: "fade"
      });



        $( "#employee" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: names,
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#employee" ).val( ui.item.label );
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#employee" ).val( ui.item.label );
                $( "#employee_id" ).val( ui.item.desc );
                return false;
            }
        })
        .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
        };


var $ac_start_date = '<?php echo $ac_end_date ?>',
    $ac_start_date_flip = '<?php echo $ac_end_date_flip ?>',
    $ac_start_parsed = Date.parse($ac_start_date),
    _today = new Date().getTime();

// For Opera and older winXP IE n such
if (isNaN($ac_start_parsed)) { 
    $ac_start_parsed  = Date.parse($ac_start_date_flip);
}

var _aDayinMS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; 

// Calculate the difference in milliseconds
var difference_ms = Math.abs($ac_start_parsed - _today);

// Convert back to days and return
var DAY_DIFFERENCE = Math.round(difference_ms/_aDayinMS);       
// do initialization here
$("#startdate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '0:+100',
            minDate: '+1d',         
            maxDate: '+' + DAY_DIFFERENCE + 'd'
});

// do initialization here
$("#enddate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '0:+100',
            minDate: '+1d',         
            maxDate: '+' + DAY_DIFFERENCE + 'd'
});

$("#doc").datepicker();

}, 'html');
return false;
});
}

function submitFormWithAjax(form) {
  form = $(form);
  $.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    type: (form.attr('method')),
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function(data){
    $(this).dialog('close');
    // Refresh table
   }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Ever heard of [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)?

Comment: Also, can you tidy up your code a little. Right now I can see that `var names` is defined in one scope and used in another (where it will be undefined).

Comment: It was working fine until I extended the array and used the options within the autocomplete. i think its the .data()._renderitem

Comment: `$(function() {var names =...});` creates a variable inside a closure-- the names variable will not be visible to other functions. That is the _first_ problem.

Answer (score 1):

u can use tagit to do that.. i think is a good option and u can achieve what u need

check this -> [How we can get the ID of selected tags using Jquery tagit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665291/how-we-can-get-the-id-of-selected-tags-using-jquery-tagit/11925654#11925654)